# sort arraylist by its first column then second column

Tags: java

I want to sort a two dimensional array list a. a is define as:
`ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()`. Currently, I would be able to sort the array a by its first column. But now, after sort by its first column, if there is a tie, I want to sort it further by compare second column. The first column is a string number (for example `"1"`) and second column is name. This is my current code for comparing first column

```
Collections.sort(a, new Comparator<ArrayList<String>>() {    
      public int compare(ArrayList<String> o1, ArrayList<String> o2) {
              return -(o1.get(0).compareTo(o2.get(0)));
         }
```

How should I modify it so I can compare both first column and second column?

Comment: Compare both columns in your comparator. Instead of "returning" the result of the compare, assign the value to to a variable. Then if the value is 0, you return the result when you compare the second column else you return the original result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. I've chosen to demonstrate using a for-loop and inline Comparator to remain as consistent as possible with your implementation:

```
Collections.sort(a, new Comparator<ArrayList<String>>() {    
    /** 
    * The idea is that we want to keep comparing the two lists if
    * there is a tie. We do this by leveraging an early return. There
    * are a couple edge cases dealing with the cases of the first N 
    * elements of o1 matching the first N elements of o2 where N is
    * the length of the smaller list. I will leave it to you to think 
    * about what you want to happen in these cases.
    */
    public int compare(ArrayList<String> o1, ArrayList<String> o2) {

        // This ensures that we don't exceed the bounds of either list.
        int sizeOfSmallerList = Math.min(o1.size(), o2.size());

        // Compare the elements at each position of the lists until 
        // a non-matching position is found.
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfSmallerList; i++) {
            int result = o2.get(i).compareTo(o1.get(i));
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return ...result when first sizeOfSmallerList elements are the same in o1 and o2...;
    }
});
```